# I'm not a Tesla

Tags: riddle, word, lateral-thinking

Here goes:

> I won't say Yes 6 months from now
>   Cast your net, as soon possible
>   To Kevin Spacey: Who won the sequel?
>   Play me once but skip the major
>   I'm not a Tesla. What am I?

Note that the grammar mistake is intentional.

**Hint #1:**

> This question was created on March 19th

**Hint #2**

> The first three lines each represent a letter (and maybe an extra symbol for one of them)

**Hint #3**

> The third line represents a number (which in turn is represented by a letter)

**Answer to the first line, my mistake with this puzzle**

> The first line is "A" - not "I"

Comment: The capital letters rearrange to WIT PICKY WITS. I'm guessing this is not relevant ...

Comment: @ Haha, no, not relevant. :)

Answer (score 3):

Again, not an answer, but I wonder......

> 6 months from March 19th is September 19th. International talk like a pirate day. I won’t be saying ‘yes’ on that day - but ‘aye’. Perhaps I’m a pirate?

I can’t link the other clues though.

Comment: rot13(NLR! Ohg lbh nera'g n cvengr - vg'f whfg n cneg bs gur chmmyr.)

Comment: You've gotten the closest so far. Check out my second hint.

Comment: Then I believe (rot13) gur nafjre gb gur svefg yvar vf “V”. Nyfb gur frpbaq yvar vf ersrerapvat Nfc.Arg fvapr gur npebalz sbe nf fbba nf cbffvoyr vf NFNC.  Gur pnfgvat bcrengbe va P# vf () znlor guvf vf fhccbfrq gb ybbx yvxr na “B”??

Comment: rot13(V thrff sbe gur svefg yvar, V cebabhapr guvf qvssreragyl (V'z terj hc Pnanqn?).
Lbh tbg gur frpbaq yvar (gur yrggre cyhf gur flzoby), abguvat eryngrq gb gur pnfg bcrengbe - gung jnf whfg n uvag gb trg crbcyr guvaxvat nobhg cebtenzzvat. 
)

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer (yet), but to get some storms started in anyone's brains: Could it be that

> Kevin Space-Y

and

> Not a Tesla (so, another Elon Musk company)

yield an answer connected to

> Space-X ?

Comment: No, not quite, and rot13(Abg eryngrq gb Ryba Zhfx). Good try though!

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> Buick?

I won't say yes 6 months from now

> I'll say "Aye" (I) -long

Cast your net, as soon as possible

> Cast your net into the sea, sharp! (C-sharp)

To Kevin Spacey: Who won the sequel?

> I don't actually know what this refers to, but judging from Hint 2 I would assume the answer is "You" (U)

Play me once but skip the major

> We're playing a musical scale that includes the note (B)

I'm not a Tesla,

> I'm a BUIC

Aside:

> Is the "sequel" a competitive event won by the **UK**?

Comment: You're getting close! For the first, line, this is my mistake - just take the first letter, I pronounce this incorrectly. I don't know why I didn't check that. *facepalm*. Your idea with the rot13(zhfvpny fpnyr) is in the right direction rot13(Gel cynlvat gur svefg guerr yvarf gbtrgure). @long Got close on one of the other lines in their answer

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is:

> Jumanji

March 19 was a Thursday, et en Francais (France) c'est "Jeudi": The first character and the last character are the same.

Jumanji is a also video game, which means that you can play it.

Comment: Hey Yuatu! No, this isn't the correct answer. Can you edit your answer with your logic for getting to this answer? What clues in the riddle did you figure out?

Comment: @VirtualValentin Are the letters that represent the 3 lines a part of the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing:

> Fall / Autumn

I note that March 19 is

> The Vernal Equinox.  (At least on the east coast of the U.S., and farther west.  The author describes himself as Romanian-American, so that fits.)

And (clutching at straws)

> a number of the clues could be seasonal references.